# HTML form to show download links based on options

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I want to make an html form that asks us to select from two lists .
Just as :

Select Profession (Select from List) : 1)Engineer 2) medical 3)accountant
Select Tools :( this list should display options according to Profession selected).

For example if Engineer is selected, it should Display options as

1)computer 2)electronics 3)mechanical.

If doctor is selected show options as
1)Cardiology 2)Gynae 3)ENT
and so on..

and there should be a button to submit options and when we click the button it should display download link (a href) for the article based on selected options.

I have no experience with html forms so kindly help me with this.

Tools options should be change according to profession.
Help me fast please. Thanks all !!

Comment: What have u tried ???

Comment: Sir, I don't know how to make html forms or use select tags and display result accordingly.

Comment: Pay me , I will do it for you :P Nobody here will code for you, if you don't have experience,then gain experience by learning them :) Learn html, JavaScript, and optional Jquery, then you will be able to do it.

Comment: M asking for help mate. That's what we call an open source world buddy :)

Comment: Google for "working with HTML forms". Or pay somebody. Most people here are for exchange knowledge, helping each other or for something really interesting. Your task can do somebody with 4 weeks experience.

Comment: @Tigran - thanks mate, will definitely google it.

Comment: Try with simple form, test it and then go next.

Comment: @Tigran - actualy I know how to make form , but problem is how to siplay the links according to the selected options and also how to make changes values in select tag based on other selected options

Comment: @ChahitKumar This will help you http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/hJ8Kz/

Comment: @TusharGupta- this helped..but now how to show  response based on both options..
IN your form if I select engineer and then en2 or en 1 or en3..it should display a download link (a href) for seeing article(for engineer en1 or en2 or en3 based on both options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code can be found, and should be credited to this site and author: [Dynamic Dropdowns](http://javascript.about.com/library/bldydrop1.htm)
However, I have reformatted it to better fit your specific question:

```
<form name="ProfessionForm">
    <div align="center">
        <select name="optone" size="1" onchange="setOptions(document.myform.optone.options[document.myform.optone.selectedIndex].value);">
            <option value=" " selected="selected">Select Profession</option>
            <option value="1">Engineer</option>
            <option value="2">Medical</option>
            <option value="3">Accounting</option>
        </select><br><br>
        <select name="opttwo" size="1">
            <option value=" " selected="selected"></option>
        </select>
        <input type="button" name="go" value="Value Selected"
            onclick="alert(document.myform.opttwo.options[document.myform.opttwo.selectedIndex].value);">
    </div>
</form>

function setOptions(chosen){
    var selbox = document.myform.opttwo;
    selbox.options.length = 0;

    if(chosen == " "){
      selbox.options[selbox.options.length] = new Option('Please select one of the options above first',' ');
    }
    if(chosen == "1"){
        selbox.options[selbox.options.length] = new Option('Aerospace','oneone');
        selbox.options[selbox.options.length] = new Option('Computer Eng','onetwo');
    }
    if (chosen == "2") {
        selbox.options[selbox.options.length] = new Option('Nurse','twoone');
        selbox.options[selbox.options.length] = new Option('Doctor','twotwo');
    }
    if (chosen == "3") {
        selbox.options[selbox.options.length] = new Option('CPA','threeone');
        selbox.options[selbox.options.length] = new Option('CFO','threetwo');
    }
}
```

Comment: this helped a lot. But this show a popup regarding selected value. I just want to show download link below the form.